# Python BMesh: index of new verts?

Tags: python, bmesh

When i try to create verts with BMesh i get always the same verts index.

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(active_obj.data)
for i in range(20):
    vert = bm.verts.new((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    print(vert.index)
```

index of all 20 verts will be -1.

How to get right index or correct it manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'll have to reassign the vertices indexes using an built in function or using your own code as [mentioned in the DOCs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVertSeq.index_update)

> index_update()
>
> ```
> Initialize the index values of this sequence.
> This is the equivalent of looping over all elements and assigning the index values.
> ```

so your code should be :

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(active_obj.data)
for i in range(20):
    vert = bm.verts.new((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    vert.index = len(bm.verts)
    print(vert.index)
```

or use

```
bm.verts.index_update()
```

Comment: bm.verts.index_update() is correct.